# XAU/USD rate in Yahoo Finance API

Tags: programming, trading, yahoofinance

My employer has asked me to implement a gold price list for our website.
I found Yahoo Finance to be a good option coding-wise, my only problem is that the value I'm getting is different from other websites that offer the info.

I'm using the following to get the value:

- [http://query.yahooapis.com](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22XAUUSD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

The rate I'm getting at the moment is: `<Rate>1323.0000</Rate>`
Compared to the rate at [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAUUSD:CUR) which is `1,157.29USD`.

Why is there a difference and which one should I use?

Comment: Very strange, I don't know what is going on. 1323 is far too high, a number between 1150 and 1160 is what I would consider correct. Basically it looks as though the Yahoo number has not been updated in months...

Comment: For yahoo, if the time given lines 6 and 7 is Eastern (not the UTC time given in the first line), that's about an hour from now. Better stock up, it looks like gold is going up :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the Bloomberg. Or there are several brokers you could use to get gold indicative prices. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api

You could even use a spread betting account and API.

I think there's a difference in rates with Bloomberg because Yahoo rate is frozen.